# Inline text in Markdown - adding results from code

Tags: r, text, r-markdown, inline, quotes

I have been told that I can write a results section for a paper on Markdown. So say I want to get the value `Robust_t_time_1` which I have derived in my R code section:

````
```{r fig.width=4, fig.height=4, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE,  
warning=FALSE, include = TRUE}

coefs.robust <- data.frame(coef(summary(model_robust)))
t_values.robust1 <- coefs.robust$t.value
Robust_t_time_1 <- t_values.robust1[3]
Robust_t_time_1

```
````

And I am writing in the text section of Markdown and I want to quote this value. How do I refer to it? I have been trying t = `{r} Robust_t_time_1` . This does not work. I know it should be possible.

Comment: ``Try `r Robust_t_time_1` ``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To evaluate the value you have to use back ticks in the text: `` "t = `r Robust_t_time_1`" ``

You can also render it as an inline equation in the text by using dollar signs: `` "$t = `r Robust_t_time_1`$" ``